# Advanced tutorial for rospy services?

Tags: rospy, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please don't link me to the beginner tutorial. This is beyond the provided examples. Let's define MySrv.srv as:

```
geometry_msgs/Point p
geometry_msgs/Vector3 v
float64 f
bool b
---
bool success
```

Then I perform the following:

```
p = Point()
v = Vector3()
req = MySrvRequest(p, v, -1, False)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
rsp = myServiceProxy(req)
```

I always get the error: `DeserializationError cannot deserialize: 'Point' object attribute 'x' is read-only`. What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291192/advanced-tutorial-for-rospy-services?/) by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 753 on 2018-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think your service structure is too complex for the calling method described in the tutorials. [This question](https://answers.ros.org/question/46643/how-to-request-a-service-with-complex-service-typein-python/) from a while may help solve your problem. You may have to construct the request object beforehand and then call the service.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-15**:
Isn't the OP already doing that? `req` is an explicitly a priori created request instance.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-05-15**:
True, they are. I miss-read that one.

**Comment by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on 2018-05-15**:
This helped me out still. Switching to the empty MySrvRequest constructor and filling in the attributes via individual assignment worked fine.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-05-15**:
Glad you got it working